# C - Exposing an interface which declares some methods to developer. Later call the implementations(defined by the developer) to run the system

Tags: c, interface, parameters, automation

I am trying to do something interesting(automation) in C. What I want to do is.

1. Expose an interface to the outer world(developer).
2. That interface declares some argument based functions.
3. Will invite developers to implement those functions.
4. The backend system will calculate some parameters.
5. Then it will call those implementations by passing the parameters(something like callback).`

It should not be a big deal. But I didn't get any success after going through "think-try" loop so many times. I am getting more and more confused every time.

I am unable to write the code to achieve the functionality. Here is some example code.

Assume I created the below interface.

```
MyInterface.h

int doSomething(int x, int y);
int doSomethingElseNow(int x, int y);
```

And asked the developer to include the header file and implement his own definitions for the above specified functions.(some thing like "Interfaces" in Java). Assume he did something like this(might be wrong)

```
Developer1.c

#include<"MyInterface.h">

int doSomething(int x, int y)
{
   return x*y;
}
int doSomethingElseNow(int x, int y)
{
   return x+y;
}
```

Now, my question is how do I call these functions(defined) from some other class. What should be my backend code. This code has to generic. It will be written before developer are asked to define functions. Want to do something like.(is wrong for sure)

```
Backend.c

#include<"MyInterface.h">

int main()
{ 
   int x, y;
   // calculating values of x and y

   //calling doSomething
   int result = doSomething(x, y);

  // doing some calculations on result variable

   //calling doSomethingElseNow
   int result2 = doSomethingElseNow(x, result);

   //do something with result2...
}
```

Please show me some direction to move on.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what part you're stuck on, exactly.  Could you clarify?

Comment: For example, #1 needs some additional information. Are you making a) a static library, b) an RPC interface, c) a DLL, or d) something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely **can** do this by only declaring and then **not implementing** your callback functions, as this will force the developer to implement them (if he doesn't, he'll get a linker error). This is what e. g. the SDL library does when it re-`#define`s the `main()` function (ugh!)

However, this is not a too wise solution. ("you can" doesn't mean "you should".) Here's why:

- On some systems, you won't be able to make a dynamic library out of your code because linkage will fail with undefined symbols.
- Only one callback function can be implemented per executable. Sometimes that's insufficient.
- The developer can't call his callback function what he wants to call it. This may even introduce name collisions.
- It is ugly and conceptually backwards.

So, instead of forcing the implementation of some arbitrarily named functions, make your interfaces expect an explicit pointer to a callback function. This is way more flexible and elegant than your current approach.

Comment: @harshitgupta well, now there's no question, actually. Youa re asking "how should I call the functions", then you answer the question yourself (`result = doSomething(x, y);`). If you know what to do, then what are you asking?

Comment: I was confused a lot, was unable to see the direct picture. Thanks a lot.